# How to prove that the square root of all non perfect squares is irrational?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I was doing this question as a homework from a lecture. I have proven that for all prime numbers, the square root is irrational using Euler’s lemma. However, I’m stuck on how to prove it for all non perfect squares. How should I approach this problem? Any help or solutions would be appreciated! Thank you so much!

Comment: Is $1/4$ considered a "non perfect square"?

Comment: There are lots of other answers to the same question on this site, besides the one I linked. Please use the search function on this site, or better yet, use google with “site:math.stackexchange.com” added to your query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n$ be a non-perfect square. Then by definition if $n = p_1^{\alpha_1}\cdots p_k^{\alpha_k}$ is the prime factorization of $n$, then at least one of the $\alpha$'s is odd. Let's say odd alphas are $\alpha_{k_1},\cdots,\alpha_{k_m}$. Then $n$ can be written as $n = A^2 \cdot \prod_{j = 1}^m p_{k_j}$ for some $A\in\mathbb{Z}$. So $\sqrt{n}$ is irrational $\iff \sqrt{\prod_{j = 1}^m p_{k_j}}$ is irrational $\iff \prod_{j = 1}^m p_{k_j} = \frac{a^2}{b^2}$ for $a,b \in\mathbb{Z}$ that are relatively prime, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).
It's best for site health to delete this answer (which also minimizes community time wasted on dupe processing.)

Comment: Can you explain how does n= A^2 . pi(pkj)?

Comment: @1937874: When you do the prime factorization of a number, some of the alpha exponents will be odd, some will be even (e.g., 72 = 2^3 * 3^2, the exponent of 2 is odd, the exponent of 3 is even). Odd exponents (i.e., 2k+1) can be written as the product of the prime and a square. (e.g.. 72 = 2^3 * 3^2 = 2*2^2  * 3^2 = (2*3)^2 * 2 = 6^2 * 2)

Comment: Sorry to ask again, but why is pi(pkj)=a^2/b^2?

Comment: @1937874 - If the square root is rational (assume for the sake of contradiction), then the squared value of the square root can be written as a^2/b^2.

Comment: But is it rational?

Comment: How can we prove that to be rational?

Comment: Kind of understand.